# Ionic iOS crash log with Ionic - swallowsDoubleTapWithScale

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, crashlytics

I have Fabric.io integrated with an Ionic app. I am getting some strange fatal crashes with Ionic 1. Some of them are related to double tap (swallowsDoubleTap issue) and some are related to transition. Some are animation-related and some of them are related to AV Playback in fullscreen and auto rotate. However, they are all Native Crashes. For these fatal crashes, debugging and Hit-&-try to the app component/areas where it should exist does not yield the expected result.

Here is one such example:

```
**[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) swallowsDoubleTapWithScale:atPoint:]
** crash logged to Fabric:

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1814d2f30 objc_msgSend + 16
1  UIKit                          0x188ebbf1c -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) swallowsDoubleTapWithScale:atPoint:] + 272
2  UIKit                          0x188d5a2c4 -[UIWebDocumentView shouldSelectionAssistantReceiveDoubleTapAtPoint:forScale:] + 108
3  UIKit                          0x188eae59c -[UIGestureRecognizerTarget _sendActionWithGestureRecognizer:] + 64
4  UIKit                          0x188eb1ca4 _UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions + 124
5  UIKit                          0x188a732e8 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 260
6  UIKit                          0x188911828 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 764
7  UIKit                          0x188ea1ce8 _UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate + 1100
8  UIKit                          0x188ea1848 -[UIGestureEnvironment _deliverEvent:toGestureRecognizers:usingBlock:] + 408
9  UIKit                          0x188ea0b04 -[UIGestureEnvironment _updateGesturesForEvent:window:] + 268
10 UIKit                          0x18890fa44 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 2960
11 UIKit                          0x1888e052c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 340
12 UIKit                          0x1890cda54 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2736
13 UIKit                          0x1890c74bc __handleEventQueue + 784
14 CoreFoundation                 0x182a34278 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
15 CoreFoundation                 0x182a33bc0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 524
16 CoreFoundation                 0x182a317c0 __CFRunLoopRun + 804
17 CoreFoundation                 0x182960048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
18 GraphicsServices               0x1843e6198 GSEventRunModal + 180
19 UIKit                          0x18894b2fc -[UIApplication _run] + 684
20 UIKit                          0x188946034 UIApplicationMain + 208
21 My_App                         0x100071050 main (main.m:32)
22 libdispatch.dylib              0x1819445b8 (Missing)
```

I looked at the following SO thread:

- [iOS - How can I decode the symbolicated crash report from iTunes Connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14825056/ios-how-can-i-decode-the-symbolicated-crash-report-from-itunesconnect)

But, the crash log there looks different from the one I have in Fabric. Do you think Fabric is messing my crash reports?

There are a lot of these and I want to know if there is any reliable way to debug such crashes? I am trying to debug with iOS crash reporting, but we haven't implemented any custom gestures or events, and just using standard click/tap events with Angular. I was wondering if there are other tools for this.

Thanks.